# Shiny conditionalPanel placeholder takes space even if condition is not met

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to shiny. I started with some basic project based on dataset with a few numeric and factor columns.

Ui section looks like this:

```html
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Title placeholder"),
  
  selectInput(inputId = "Variable", label = strong("Choose variable"),
              choices = colnames(data[,colnames(data)!="ID"]),
              selected = "A"), 
  sliderInput(inputId = "BinsHistogram", label = "Choose no. histogram bins:", min = 5, max = 50, value = 20),
  

  conditionalPanel('input.Variable %in% c("A", "B", "C")', plotOutput("Histogram")),
  conditionalPanel('input.Variable %in% c("D", "E", "F")', plotOutput("Groups"))

)
```

The problem is that if "Groups" plot is applicable, shiny is displaying it at the bottom of the site, leaving placeholder space for "Histogram" plot, even though it is not displayed (that's what I suppose). How can I avoid that, so the "Groups" plot displays right below UI controls?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  The `condition` argument to `conditionalPanel` needs to be written in javascript, not R.  I'm not an expert, but I don't think `%in%` is valid javascript, so I'm guessing the expression is (somehow) evaluating to TRUE and hence you get a blank histogram.  Rewrite your condition.

Comment: I changed conditions to: conditionalPanel('input.Variable == "A" || 'input.Variable ==  "B" || 'input.Variable ==  "C")), unfortunately did not solve the problem. EDIT: There was a typo, your suggestion solved the problem, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Limey in the comments, you'll need a valid JS condition:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Title placeholder"),
  selectInput(inputId = "Variable", label = strong("Choose variable"),
              choices = LETTERS[1:6], selected = "A"), 
  sliderInput(inputId = "BinsHistogram", label = "Choose no. histogram bins:", min = 5, max = 50, value = 20),
  conditionalPanel('["A", "B", "C"].includes(input.Variable)', plotOutput("Histogram")),
  # alternativ: input.Variable == "A" || input.Variable == "B" || input.Variable == "C"
  conditionalPanel('["D", "E", "F"].includes(input.Variable)', plotOutput("Groups"))
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Histogram <- output$Groups <- renderPlot({plot(1:10, main = input$Variable)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```